# React Router Link Not Working After Render in IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have run into an issue where React Router's NavLink is not working upon the initial render of a dashboard screen, after a successful login. After trying many different things I am posting here. You probably won't know why either but its worth a shot.

An example layout of the dashboard is as follows:

```
<div>
  <nav>
    <NavLink>Link 1</NavLink>
    <NavLink>Link 2</NavLink>
    <NavLink>Link 3</NavLink>
    <NavLink>Link 4</NavLink>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <!-- CONTENT -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Upon initial render Link 2 will be unresponsive, while Link 1, 3, and 4 work fine. Clicking Link 3 for example will render new elements in the content section and  *then* Link 2 will work.

I have tried even changing the NavLinks to anchor tags and adding my own click handler, but no matter what I try the second Link will not work until some mysterious event takes place.

Any ideas?

**Edit*** Add routes for @arracso

Authenticated Route:

```
 <Switch>
      <Route path="/route-1" component={SomeComponent} />
      <Route path="/*" component={Dashboard} />
 </Switch>
```

Dashboard:

```
<Row>
  {navigationElement}
  <Column>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/1" component={A} />
      <Route exact path="/2" component={B} />
      <Route path="/2/1" component={C} />
      <Route path="/2/1" component={D} />
    </Switch>
  </Column>
</Row>
```

Comment: can you show us the routes? So we can see whats happening

Comment: @arracso added routes

Comment: I supose you are using react-router v4, I tried to open my own react web on IE 11 and it worked propertly. I would try the following: **1.** Remove `path="/*"` **2.** add `exact` to all routes. **3** Switch only renders one route so `<Route path="/2/1" component={D} />` would never be rendered. **4.** Look if the component it isn't rendering have to load some data so it needs time or something. If you can't find the solution please add more code.